# Como somar valores de um grande grupo de colunas?

Tags: python, banco-de-dados

Boa tarde, pessoal.

Estou estudando Python para análise de dados e tenho o seguinte problema: eu tenho uma base de dados com varias colunas e gostaria de fazer uma soma delas sem precisar especificar o nome de cada uma delas e sem somar a última coluna. Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu poderia somar cada uma das colunas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas acho que essa não é a melhor forma de fazer em uma base com muitas colunas.

Obrigado a todos pela a atenção e boas festas.

Answer (score 1):

Há várias formas de conseguir essa soma. A melhor para as necessidades do programador dependerá da situação.

Para a tabela apresentada (pf, escrever as perguntas colocando código em vez de capturas de ecrã):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3],
                   'b': [2, 3, 4],
                   'c': [5, 9, 1],
                   'd': [3, 7, 9]})
```

Podemos somar tudo e subtrair o que não queremos:

```
df['soma'] = df.sum(axis = 1) - df['d']
```

Outra forma é usando a ferramenta `apply()` com uma função adequada:

```
f = lambda x: sum(x[:-1])
df['soma'] = df.apply(f, axis = 1)
```

Na primeira alternativa, usou-se o nome da coluna. Na segunda, utilizou-se o facto de se saber que a coluna que não deve ser somada é a última.

Outra alternativa, talvez um pouco mais versátil que as anteriores, é obter a lista de colunas e depois manipular a lista em função das necessidades:

```
colunas = list(df)
colunas.remove('d') 
# ou qualquer outro metodo de manipulacao de listas
# neste caso remove() porque lhe estamos a fornecer o nome da coluna a remover
df['soma'] = df[colunas].sum(axis = 1)
```

Há ainda a possibilidade de usar `iloc()`, fatiando (?) adequadamente.